# Find the derivative of $y = x^{\ln(x)}\sec(x)^{3x}$

Tags: derivatives

What is the derivative of 
  $$y = x^{\ln(x)}\sec(x)^{3x}$$

I tried to find the derivative of this function but somewhere along the way I seem to have gotten lost. I started off with using the product rule and then the chain rule about 4 times and things are getting messier. Now I just don't know what to do. I would show my work here but that would be roughly 2 whole pages of calculations...

Comment: Show some of your work. Where are you getting stuck?\

Answer (score 2):

First let's rewrite $x^{\log x} = e^{\log x\log x} = e^{\log^2 x}$ and $\sec^{3x}(x) = e^{3x\log(\sec x)}$ Then,
$$
f'(x) = \sec^{3x}(x) \left(e^{\log^2 x}\right)' + e^{\log^2 x}\left(e^{3x\log(\sec x)}\right)'
$$
Observe that 
$$
\left(e^{\log^2 x}\right)'  = 2\frac{\log x}{x}e^{\log^2 x}
$$
and
$$
\left(e^{3x\log(\sec x)}\right)' = \left(3(\log(\sec x)) + 3x\left(\frac{1}{\sec x}\sec x \tan x\right)\right)e^{3x\log(\sec x)} 
$$

Can you continue from here?

EDIT: As a rule of thumb, when having variable exponents you must use the fact that $\exp\circ\log = \operatorname{Id}$ to turn them into products.

Comment: I'll give it a go and see how it turns out, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try logarithmic differentiation, or somehow make use the fact that $a=e^{\ln a}$ for $a>0$. (you have to decide what $a$ should be).

Answer (score 0):

Derivatives of powers are conveniently obtained using logarithms.

$$y = x^{\ln(x)}\sec(x)^{3x}=e^{\ln^2x+3x\ln\sec x}.$$

For later simplification, we note that by the definition of the secant, $\ln\sec x=-\ln\cos x$.

Then the derivative of an exponential is the same exponential. Using the chain rule,

$$y'=(\ln^2x-3x\ln\cos x)'y.$$

The derivative of a square is twice the argument. Using the chain rule,

$$(\ln^2x)'=(\ln x)'2\ln x=2\frac{\ln x}x.$$

The derivative of a product is the sum of each factor times the derivative of the other,

$$(3x\ln\cos x)'=3\ln\cos x+3x(\ln\cos x)'.$$

And finally by the chain rule,
$$(\ln\cos x)'=-\frac{\sin x}{\cos x}=-\tan x.$$

Putting all results together,

$$y'=(2\frac{\ln x}x-3\ln\cos x+3x\tan x)x^{\ln(x)}\sec(x)^{3x}.$$